# I want to bind data From two different views

Tags: .net, maui

I have two views one is parent view (Ics view) in which I have added child view (side View).
In IcsView I have written code for buttons add file and add folder now I want to bind that data in child view i.e. side view.

Model:

```
  public partial class Data:ObservableObject
{
    public string filePath { get; set; }
    public String FilePath
    {
        get { return filePath; }    
        set { filePath = value; }
    }
}
```

Ics xaml:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="ICSViewer.MVVM.View.IcsView"
         xmlns:v="clr-namespace:ICSViewer.MVVM.View"
         xmlns:model="clr-namespace:ICSViewer.MVVM.ViewModel"
         >
<ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <model:IcsViewModel/>
</ContentPage.BindingContext>
<ContentPage.MenuBarItems>
```

<v:SideView  Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="3" />

IcsView Code Behind:

```
 private readonly IFolderPicker _folderPicker;
public static List<Data> Items = new List<Data>();
public IcsView(IFolderPicker folderPicker)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    _folderPicker = folderPicker;
}

private async void Add_File(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    var CustomFileType = new FilePickerFileType(new Dictionary<DevicePlatform, IEnumerable<String>>
    {
        { DevicePlatform.WinUI, new[]{"ics"} },
    });
    var results = await FilePicker.PickMultipleAsync(new PickOptions
    {
        FileTypes = CustomFileType,
    });
  
    foreach (var result in results)
    {

        FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(result.FullPath);


        double size = fileSize(fileInfo);
        bool fileExist = false;
        foreach (Data item in Items)
        {
            if (item.FilePath.Equals(result.FullPath))
            {
                fileExist = true;
                break;
            }

        }
        if (!fileExist)
        {
            Items.Add(new Data
            {
                FilePath = result.FullPath,
                
            });
        }
        else
        {
        
            await DisplayAlert("Alert", "File already exist!", "Ok");
        }
    }
    

}

public void getFiles(FileInfo path)
{
    double size = fileSize(path);
    bool fileExist = false;
    foreach (Data item in Items)
    {
        if (item.FilePath.Equals(path.FullName))
        {
            fileExist = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!fileExist)
    {
        Items.Add(new Data
        {
            FilePath = path.FullName,
           
        });
    }
  
}
public double fileSize(FileInfo file)
{
    double fileSize = file.Length;

    double sizeMb = fileSize * 0.000001;
    return Math.Round(sizeMb, 2);
}
```

SideView

```
 <StackLayout>
    <Label  Text="{Binding SideModel.HeaderText}" FontSize="18" FontAttributes="Bold" Padding="5" />
    <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Reference childView }, Path=icsViewModel.Items}">
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Label Text="{Binding FilePath}"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>

</StackLayout>
```

This is Code behind of sideView

```
public string FilePath
{
    get
    {
        string value = (String)GetValue(FilePathProperty);
        return value;
    }
    set
    {
        SetValue(FilePathProperty, value);
    }
}
static void OnFileNameChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
{
    Console.WriteLine("-----------------> " + newValue);
}
public static readonly BindableProperty MyViewModelProperty =
       BindableProperty.Create(
nameof(IcsViewModel),
           typeof(IcsViewModel),
           typeof(SideView),
null);
public static readonly BindableProperty FilePathProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(File)
   , typeof(Data)
   , typeof(SideView), defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.TwoWay, propertyChanged: OnFileNameChanged);

public IcsViewModel icsViewModel
{
    set { SetValue(MyViewModelProperty, value); }
    get { return (IcsViewModel)GetValue(MyViewModelProperty); }
}
public SideView()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    
}
```

Updated view Model:
I haven't added set method in here. and I m not getting how I should add that property in here. so can you please go through it once.

namespace DataBinding.MVVM.ViewModel
{
internal partial class ParentViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

```
    public ObservableCollection<Data> Item { get; set; }
    public ParentViewModel()
        {
            Item = new ObservableCollection<Data>();
        }
    [RelayCommand]
    public async void Add_File()
    {
        var CustomFileType = new FilePickerFileType(new Dictionary<DevicePlatform, IEnumerable<String>>
    {
        { DevicePlatform.WinUI, new[]{"ics"} },
    });
        var results = await FilePicker.PickMultipleAsync(new PickOptions
        {
            FileTypes = CustomFileType,
        });

        foreach (var result in results)
        {
            FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(result.FullPath);
            double size = fileSize(fileInfo);
            bool fileExist = false;
            foreach (Data item in Item)
            {
                if (item.name.Equals(result.FullPath))
                {
                    fileExist = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!fileExist)
            {
                Item.Add(new Data
                {
                    name = result.FullPath,
                });
            }
            else
            {
                Item = Item;
            }
        }
    }

    public void getFiles(FileInfo path)
    {
        double size = fileSize(path);
        bool fileExist = false;
        foreach (Data item in Item)
        {
            if (item.name.Equals(path.FullName))
            {
                fileExist = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!fileExist)
        {
            Item.Add(new Data
            {
                name = path.FullName,

            });
        }

    }
    public double fileSize(FileInfo file)
    {
        double fileSize = file.Length;
        double sizeMb = fileSize * 0.000001;
        return Math.Round(sizeMb, 2);
    }

    bool SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (Object.Equals(storage, value))
            return false;
        storage = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }
    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

}

If I select particular file then I want that file or folder to be populated in my side view.
And I am not able to bind data from IcsView.xaml.cs to sideview.xaml.cs

Comment: Whenever you need to bind to two different sources, the solution is to use `Source=...` in some of the bindings. I have not read through the details of your question, but its likely that you can use `x:Reference` to an `x:Name`, OR use `RelativeSource` with the `Type` of the parent view. Research those uses of Binding Source.

Comment: Can you please share any example with me @ToolmakerSteve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved your function based on MVVM.It works on my side.

You can refer to the following code:

**MyViewModel.cs**

```
public class MyViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged 
    {

        public int index = 0;
        public ObservableCollection<Data> Items { get; set; }


        private string _testName;
        public string TestName
        {
            set { SetProperty(ref _testName, value); }
            get { return _testName; }
        }

        public ICommand ChangeNameCommand => new Command(changeMethod);

        public ICommand PickDataCommand => new Command(addItemMethod);

        private void addItemMethod(object obj)
        {
            Add_File();
        }

        private void changeMethod()
        {
            index++;

            TestName = "change data" + index;

            Items.Add(new Data { FilePath= TestName });
        }

        public MyViewModel()
        {
            TestName = "test string";

            Items = new ObservableCollection<Data>();
        }

        public async void Add_File()
        {
            var results = await FilePicker.PickMultipleAsync(new PickOptions
            {
                //FileTypes = customFileType
            });

            foreach (var result in results)
            {
                bool fileExist = false;

                foreach (Data item in Items) {
                    if (item != null) {
                        if (result.FileName.Equals(item.FileName))  // here I don't suggest compare `FilePath`,sometimes, if we select the same image, the FullPath maybe different  (result.FullPath.Equals(item.FilePath))
                        {
                            fileExist = true;
                            break;
                        }
                        else {
                            continue;
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (!fileExist) { 
                   Items.Add( new Data {  FilePath= result.FullPath,FileName= result.FileName });
                }
            }

        }

        bool SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            if (Object.Equals(storage, value))
                return false;
            storage = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
            return true;
        }
        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }
```

**Data.cs**

```
public class Data 
{
    public string FilePath { get; set; }

    public string FileName { get; set; }
}
```

**ChildView.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<ContentView xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MauiContentViewApp.ChildView"
             x:Name="TestControlView"
             >
    <VerticalStackLayout>
        <Label   Text="{Binding Source={x:Reference TestControlView}, Path=YourName}"
            VerticalOptions="Center" 
            HorizontalOptions="Center" />


        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Reference TestControlView}, Path=myViewModel.Items }" HasUnevenRows="True" >
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <Label Text="{Binding FileName}" TextColor="#f35e20"  VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentView>
```

**ChildView.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class ChildView : ContentView 
{
    public String YourName
    {
        get
        {
            String value = (String)GetValue(YourNameProperty);
            return value;
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(YourNameProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty YourNameProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(YourName)
    , typeof(String)
    , typeof(ChildView), defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.TwoWay, propertyChanged: OnYourNameChanged);

    static void OnYourNameChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("-----------------> " + newValue);
    }


    //add MyViewModelProperty
    public static readonly BindableProperty myViewModelProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(
            nameof(myViewModel),
            typeof(MyViewModel),
            typeof(ChildView),
            null);

    public MyViewModel myViewModel
    {
        set { SetValue(myViewModelProperty, value); }
        get { return (MyViewModel)GetValue(myViewModelProperty); }
    }


    public ChildView()
      {
            InitializeComponent();
      }
}
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage 
{
    public MainPage()
      {
            InitializeComponent();

      }
}
```

**MainPage.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:mauiapp="clr-namespace:MauiContentViewApp"
             x:Class="MauiContentViewApp.MainPage"
             x:Name="mainpage"
             >

    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <mauiapp:MyViewModel></mauiapp:MyViewModel>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>

    <ScrollView>
        <VerticalStackLayout>
            <Label Text="{Binding Name}" IsVisible="false"></Label>
            
            <mauiapp:ChildView YourName="{Binding TestName}" myViewModel="{Binding Path=BindingContext, Source={x:Reference mainpage}}"></mauiapp:ChildView>

            <Button  Text="Change"  Command="{Binding ChangeNameCommand}" IsVisible="false"></Button>

            <Button Text="Add file" Command="{Binding PickDataCommand}"></Button>
        </VerticalStackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</ContentPage>
```

**Note:**

1.Please add permission in file `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

2.In fact, to achieve such a function, there is no need to create a new `ContentView` (`ChildView`) separately, which increases the difficulty of the code. You can add the `ListView` to the parent page directly.

You can check another way to achieve this function here: ['The active Window can not be detected. Ensure that you have called Init in your Application class.'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74386720/the-active-window-can-not-be-detected-ensure-that-you-have-called-init-in-your/74440440#74440440) .

Answer (score 0):

> I have two views one is parent view (Ics view) in which I have added
> child view (side View)

If the `side View` is included in parent view (`Ics view`), a common method is to refer to the parent variable in the parent view's view model.

In this condition, you can create a `BindableProperty` in your `side View`.

I have created a simple demo to simulate this problem (My parent view is `MainPage`  and the child view is `ChildView`).

You can refer to the following code:

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage 
{
      public MainPage()
      {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.BindingContext =  new MyViewModel();
      }
}
```

MainPage.xaml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:mauiapp="clr-namespace:MauiContentViewApp"
             x:Class="MauiContentViewApp.MainPage"
             x:Name="mainpage"
             >

    <ScrollView>
        <VerticalStackLayout>
            <Label Text="{Binding Name}"></Label>
            <mauiapp:ChildView YourName="{Binding TestName}" MyViewModel="{Binding Path=BindingContext, Source={x:Reference mainpage}}"></mauiapp:ChildView>
            
            
            <Button Command="{Binding ChangeNameCommand}"></Button>
        </VerticalStackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</ContentPage>
```

MyViewModel.cs

```
   public class MyViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int index = 0;

    public ObservableCollection<string> Items { get; set; }

    private string _testName;
    public string TestName
    {
        set { SetProperty(ref _testName, value); }
        get { return _testName; }
    }

    public ICommand ChangeNameCommand => new Command(changeMethod);


    private void changeMethod()
    {
        index++;

        TestName = "change data" + index;

        Items.Add(TestName);
    }

    public MyViewModel()
    {
        Name = "abc";
        TestName = "test string";

        Items = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    }
    bool SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (Object.Equals(storage, value))
            return false;
        storage = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }
    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

ChildView.xaml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<ContentView xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MauiContentViewApp.ChildView"
             x:Name="TestControlView"
             >
    <VerticalStackLayout>
        <Label   Text="{Binding Source={x:Reference TestControlView}, Path=YourName}"
            VerticalOptions="Center" 
            HorizontalOptions="Center" />


        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Reference TestControlView}, Path=MyViewModel.Items }" >
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <Label Text="{Binding .}" TextColor="#f35e20" />
       
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentView>
```

ChildView.xaml.cs

```
    public partial class ChildView : ContentView 
{
    public String YourName
    {
        get
        {
            String value = (String)GetValue(YourNameProperty);
            return value;
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(YourNameProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty YourNameProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(YourName)
    , typeof(String)
    , typeof(ChildView), defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.TwoWay, propertyChanged: OnYourNameChanged);

    static void OnYourNameChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("-----------------> " + newValue);
    }


    //add MyViewModelProperty
    public static readonly BindableProperty MyViewModelProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(
            nameof(MyViewModel),
            typeof(MyViewModel),
            typeof(ChildView),
            null);

    public MyViewModel MyViewModel
    {
        set { SetValue(MyViewModelProperty, value); }
        get { return (MyViewModel)GetValue(MyViewModelProperty); }
    }


    public ChildView()
      {
            InitializeComponent();
      }
}
```

**Note:**

1.Here, I create a viewmodel `MyViewModel` for the `MainPage`, and in the viewmodel, I create a variabe `TestName` for the ChildView and implemented interface `INotifyPropertyChanged`  for `MyViewModel`.Once changing the value of `TestName`, the UI will refresh automatically on the `ChildView`.

2.If you want to add a `ListView` into the `ChildView`, you can add a new BindableProperty  `MyViewModelProperty`   into `ChildView.xaml.cs` and add a `ObservableCollection Items`  to ViewModel `MyViewModel`

```
 public ObservableCollection<string> Items { get; set; }
```

**Update:**

I couldn't see other codes of your app, but from the code you posted, I found there are several problems.

1.you can recheck if you have set the `BindingContext`  for page `IcsView` .

For example:

```
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage 
   {
      public MainPage()
      {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.BindingContext =  new MyViewModel();
      }
    }
```

2.you can debug to see if you have got the updated data for `Items` in your ViewModel .

You also need to change code:

```
  public static List<Data> Items = new List<Data>();
```

to

```
  public   ObservableCollection<Data> Items { get; set; }
```

And initialize it in the constructor of your viewmodel

```
 Items = new ObservableCollection<Data>();
```

3.Your custom property `icsViewModel` is used incorrectly.

The naming convention for bindable properties is that the bindable property identifier must match the property name specified in the Create method, with "Property" appended to it. For more information, check:[Create a bindable property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/bindable-properties#create-a-bindable-property).

You can refer to the following code:

```
//add myViewModelProperty ,it should be `myViewModel`+`Property`.
public static readonly BindableProperty myViewModelProperty =
    BindableProperty.Create(
        nameof(myViewModel),  //here it should be the same as the following property `myViewModel`
        typeof(MyViewModel),
        typeof(ChildView),
        null);

public MyViewModel myViewModel
{
    set { SetValue(myViewModelProperty, value); }
    get { return (MyViewModel)GetValue(myViewModelProperty); }
}
```

Comment: How can I apply to the collection? and I want to set those items in collection view

Comment: I have updated my reply, you can check my answer.

Comment: ok @Jessie zhang

Comment: I have added my updated code Can you please check once what I have done wrong?@Jessie Zhang

Comment: I have updated my answer. You can check the updated part at the bottom of my answer.  If the problems in your app persist, could you please post a basic demo so that I can help you better?

Comment: Here Data is data model. That's the reason I have used like observableCollection<Data>. Is it correct or wrong ? and I have bind context in icsView.xaml.

Comment: It doesn't matter if the `Data ` is Model. Sorry, I forgot to replace `string` with `Data ` in the answer. I have updated the code.  `public   ObservableCollection<Data> Items { get; set; }`   and  `Items = new ObservableCollection<Data>();`

Comment: Ok I have done all the changes you told. I am still not getting list populated in my side view.

Comment: Could you please post a basic demo to github or onedriver so that I can test on my side? The code I shared above works properly on my side.

Comment: Sorry I can't share my code.

Comment: Is there any problem with sharing? You can also share the latest and the full code of your code of parent view (Ics view) and child view (side View) here.

Comment: Can you please check my view model once. I think I have done something wrong there

Comment: I couldn't see the latest code of your app? Is your main page a `ContentPage` type? What is the code of  `parent view (Ics view)`? Is there a button on it that triggers the event?

Comment: Could you please post the latest code of your `parent view (Ics view)` and the `child view (side View)`(including the `xaml` and `.xaml.cs`)?

Comment: Can you please share any example with model ? Like you where you have model person with string name and then your adding that name in view in viewmodel? something like this ?

Comment: I have updated my code you can check it now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249468/discussion-between-jessie-zhang-msft-and-preeti-jadhav).