# Create re-usable RadioButtonGroupView control

Tags: .net, xaml, maui

I have managed to get a radio button group functionality working with the following XAML:

```xml
<ScrollView>
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Devices}"
              Style="{StaticResource ListViewSimpleStyle}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell x:DataType="local:DeviceEntryModel">
                    <RadioButton IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                 GroupName="Devices">
                        <RadioButton.Content>
                            <Label BindingContext="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type RadioButton}}, Path=BindingContext}"
                                   Text="{Binding Name}"
                                   IsEnabled="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type RadioButton}}, Path=IsEnabled}" />
                        </RadioButton.Content>
                    </RadioButton>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</ScrollView>
```

Is there any way to simplify this and make it more re-usable? I was thinking of and end result that looks like this:

```xml
<RadioButtonGroupView ItemSource="{Binding Devices}">
    <RadioButtonGroupView.ItemTemplate>
      <RadioButton IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}"
                   x:DataType="local:Device"
                   GroupName="Devices">
            <Label BindingContext="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type RadioButton}}, Path=BindingContext}"
                   Text="{Binding Name}"
                   IsEnabled="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type RadioButton}}, Path=IsEnabled}" />
        </RadioButton>
    </RadioButtonGroupView.ItemTemplate>
</RadioButtonGroupView>
```

Something along those lines, something simpler, you get the gist. Thanks!

I tried something with bindable properties but not sure it's the right approach.

Comment: Remove `ScrollView`. `ListView` is already scrollable. Once you've made that change, there are no important differences between your original, and your "more reusable" version; you've just replaced `ListView` with `RadioButtonGroupView`. If you really care to make a reusable control, look for examples of creating a "custom control". Importantly, learn about `BindableProperty`, which is needed to pass values from a surrounding page to your custom control. That's what makes a custom control useful.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve I know it is, but in reality removing `ScrollView` breaks the functionality.  I know it shouldn't, could be a MAUI bug - the list view would crash (on Android at least) if scrolling too fast.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if you want to reuse the control, you can create a `ContentView` with relative `BindableProperty`.

Here is a sample code:

**ChildView.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<ContentView xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MauiContentViewApp.ChildView"
             x:Name="TestControlView"
             >
    <VerticalStackLayout>
        <Label   Text="{Binding Source={x:Reference TestControlView}, Path=YourName}"
            VerticalOptions="Center" 
            HorizontalOptions="Center" />


        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Reference TestControlView}, Path=myViewModel.Items }" HasUnevenRows="True" >
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <Label Text="{Binding FileName}" TextColor="#f35e20"  VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentView>
```

**ChildView.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class ChildView : ContentView 
{
    public String YourName
    {
        get
        {
            String value = (String)GetValue(YourNameProperty);
            return value;
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(YourNameProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty YourNameProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(YourName)
    , typeof(String)
    , typeof(ChildView), defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.TwoWay, propertyChanged: OnYourNameChanged);

    static void OnYourNameChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("-----------------> " + newValue);
    }


    //add MyViewModelProperty
    public static readonly BindableProperty myViewModelProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(
            nameof(myViewModel),
            typeof(MyViewModel),
            typeof(ChildView),
            null);

    public MyViewModel myViewModel
    {
        set { SetValue(myViewModelProperty, value); }
        get { return (MyViewModel)GetValue(myViewModelProperty); }
    }


    public ChildView()
      {
            InitializeComponent();
      }
}
```

For more details, you can check thread [I want to bind data From two different views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74317026/i-want-to-bind-data-from-two-different-views/74440247#74440247).

You can check document [BindableProperty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/bindable-properties)  for more information.

Comment: Waiting for your good news. :)

Answer (score 1):

You need XAML and .CS parts.

In the XAML you define your ControlTemplate.
Put everything UI there, and either use TemplatedParent as source or specify that you use TemplateBinding.

In the .CS, you create the core of your control, inheriting ContentView, and writing all BindableProperties that you have been using in the XAML. (I assume Value and ItemSource will be your minimum).

However, I want you to think for a second. IF your model is "Device", how reusable your control should be? If you have, for example, a popup that lets you pick from list of Devices, in most cases the Popup is your reusable part, not the radio button group.

Just something to think about, when you make design choices. Nothing is stopping you from making custom controls, however.

Comment: I guess you're right, maybe I'm trying to split hairs here. Part of my job is also JavaScript development, and our framework allows to do something like [this](https://pastecode.io/s/z00ubdqk). I find this far more elegant, and wanted to see if something similar could be achieved with XAML.